# Selectina String and Doubleclicking using Selenium Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got a disabled textbox with below tags:

```
<div 
id="writingactivityId2" class="boxSize ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required redactor_editor writingActivityDisabled" ng-focus="editing()" redactor="" readonly="" ng-model="workInProgress.wip" required="" contenteditable="false" dir="ltr" style="height: 300px;">
</div>
```

and it has a child:

```
<p>
Automated Test 04/03/2015 15:03:43
</p>
```

Can any one suggest how to select the Text "Automated" Or double click/single on the text "Automated"?

I tried to point the webElement on `div` and on `p` when I tried double click it selects the whole page rather than selecting the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer will be a bit different for different OS. For win it will be like:

```
WebElement textElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#writingactivityId2 p"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(textElement).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")).perform();
```

Comment: Thanks Stanger, I used action.moveToElement(webElement,10,10).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).click().perform(); which worked. Since its a disabled text area using Ctr+a will select the whole page. The above worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the element using, for example, a *CSS selector*:

```
WebElement p = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#writingactivityId2 p"));
```

Comment: Hi, i tried that. I tried to point the driver on webElement div and on P as well. when i tried doubleclick it selects the whole page rather than selecting the text inside the P. I want so select only the "Automated" Text/String.

Comment: @SPatchamatla okay, what is your end goal? Why do you want to double click the p element? Thanks.

Comment: my goal is to highlight/Select the text "Automated". When i select the text, our application enables a option to edit on top of the text.

Comment: @SPatchamatla thanks for the information. Could you try clicking or double-clicking on the `div#writingactivityId2` element? I don't actually think `p` element is "actionable".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dobuleclicked on the div#writingactivityId2 using the cssselector and it selects the whole page since the div#writingactivityId2 is disabled text area

Comment: @SPatchamatla hm. Is it a public site so that I can reproduce the problem? If not, could you provide the complete HTML representation of the editor? Thanks.

Comment: it's a internal site, unfortunately i cannot give access to it, but i tried the same on gmail page, where i want in a similar kind of action like highlighting the text "Experience" which is div h4 text value. I took a screen shot and attached here::http://imgur.com/Fieq6ej

Comment: @SPatchamatla thanks, Stanjer's answer looks promising, have you tried that?